# Yii - CActiveDataProvider using relations

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I am trying to use relations as part of the criteria to create a `CActiveDataProvider`. I have the following:

User model:

```
return array(
        'favourites'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserFavourite', 'user_id', 'order'=>'added_at DESC'),
);
```

---

UserFavourite model:

```
return array(
        'user'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
        'listing'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Listing', 'listing_id'),
);
```

---

Controller (view favourites action):

```
$user = $this->loadUser(Yii::app()->user->id);
```

---

How do I create a `CActiveDataProvider` in my User model that fetches all `favourites` by the current user - along with the related `listing` model data for each favourite? So I want to do something like `$favourites = $user->getFavourites();`.

The `CActiveDataProvider` should return an array of `Listing` objects. It should support pagination and sorting - the default sort will be `added_at DESC`.

I have tried using the `with` option of `CDbCriteria` but that does not seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I have achieved the required output:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = 'uf.user_id = :user_id';
$criteria->params = array(':user_id'=>$this->id);
$criteria->join = 'LEFT OUTER JOIN user_favourite uf ON uf.listing_id = t.id';
$criteria->order = 'uf.added_at DESC';

return new CActiveDataProvider('Listing', array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
));
```

In the end I have just hard-coded in the JOIN, rather than try and use the relation, as it seems it is not meant to work that way.

Answer (score 7):

You have not provided your database schema, but i guess this code could work,

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->with=array('favourites'=>array('with'=>'listing'));
$dataProvider= new CActiveDataProvider('User', array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort'=>array(
            'defaultOrder'=>'t.added_at DESC',
        )));
```

Please make sure your **Relations** are correct and according to schema.

- Infact, If you dont care about number of queries, you can always call something like

  $user->favourites;

It will return proper data for correct relations, Again you can do this

**In order to**, pass listing model to view go like this

```
foreach($user->favourites as $fav){

  $this->renderPartial("PATH TO YOUR VIEW",array('data'=>$fav->listing));

}
```

Note that there may be many Favourites for an user so you need to use foreach , unless you are not using **CListview**.
Another way is to user **Clistview** in that case you may need to change your query.Let me know how that works for you.

Comment: That has not worked I'm afraid. Because the CActiveDataProvider is loading the `User` class, but my view files are expecting a `Listing` class. It must return an array of `Listing` class object.

The relations are correct, and I can get the correct data by doing `$user->favourites` as you have suggested, but the problem is it won't let me use that relation as the source of my CActiveDataProvider.

Also I'm aware I can create a separate function that will return the required data without using the relation. But I prefer not to repeat any code. Is this a limitation we just have to live with?

Comment: if Your view files are expecting **Listing Model**, why don' you just pass the listing model to view, check edited answer for detail.

Comment: I am in fact using CListView. So I am not able to pass in the Listing model, I am only able to specify a `dataProvider` value.

Comment: In that case , You need to modify your query and create **Dataprovider** for Listing, Answer by @codeFX seems right for that why don't you give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Listing`  `relations` method you need to have the relations to
`Users` through the intermediate table `UsersFavourite`. The relationship type
is HAS_MANY:

```
return array(
         'favourites'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserFavourite', 'listing_id'),
         'users'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'User', array('user_id'=>'id'), 'through'=>'favourites')
);
```

In your `User` method that returns the `CActiveDataProvider`: The main model
is `Listing`, joined to `UserFavourite` and `User`. You must set `together`
 to `true` to build one single sql query. Finally you must set the users.id to
the current id of `User` model to bring only the rows relevant to the current user.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with = array( 'favourites','users =>'array('condition'=>"users.id=:user_id"));
$criteria->together = true;
$criteria->params = array(':user_id'=>$this->id);

return new CActiveDataProvider('Listing', array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort'=>array('defaultOrder'=>'favourites.added_at DESC')
));
```

I tested this answer and worked correctly with a small dataset.